# ITMS-90869: Invalid Bundle. The bundle 'bar.app' supports arm64 but not Intel. Your build must include the x86_64 architecture to support Intel

Tags: macos, electron, electron-builder

This problem occurs on 'macOS Monterey'

I am running into an issue where `electron-builder` is building `mas-arm64` builds. It used to build `mas` builds. I have reverted all the code changes I made recently and I am still running into the same issue.

The full error message in the transporter is:

```
ERROR ITMS-90869: "Invalid Bundle. The bundle 'bar.app' supports arm64 but not Intel. Your build must include the x86_64 architecture to support Intel. For more about supporting Intel-based Mac computers, see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/building-a-universal-macos-binary"
```

The npm electron-build output is:

```
>> bar$ sudo npm run electron-build

> bar@0.8.4 preelectron-pack

> npm run build-react



> bar@0.8.4 build-react

> cross-env REACT_APP_ENV=PROD react-scripts build


Creating an optimized production build...

> bar@0.8.4 electron-pack

> electron-builder -m "mas"


  • electron-builder  version=22.10.5 os=21.2.0

  • loaded configuration  file=package.json ("build" field)

  • writing effective config  file=dist/builder-effective-config.yaml

  • packaging       platform=mas arch=arm64 electron=13.2.0 appOutDir=dist/mas-arm64

  • Unpacking electron zip  zipPath=undefined

  • signing         file=dist/mas-arm64/bar.app identityName=Developer ID Application: xxxxxxxx (yyyyyyyyyy) identityHash=zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz provisioningProfile=certs/bar.provisionprofile

  • signing         file=dist/mas-arm64/Bar.app identityName=3rd Party Mac Developer Application: xxxxxxxxxxxx (yyyyyyyy) identityHash=zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz provisioningProfile=certs/Bar.provisionprofile
```

My package.json is:

```
{
  scripts: {..., "electron-build": "electron-builder -m"}
  build: {
  ...,
    "mac": {
      "icon": "icons/icon.icns",
      "category": "public.app-category.xxxxxxxx",
      "entitlements": "entitlements.mas.plist",
      "entitlementsInherit": "entitlements.mas.plist",
      "provisioningProfile": "provisioning/bar.provisionprofile",
      "extraResources": [
        "electron/bin/**/*"
      ],
      "target": [
        "mas"
      ],
      "binaries": [],
      "extendInfo": {
        "NSMicrophoneUsageDescription": "Bar requires microphone access."
      }
    },
 }
}
```

I tried to create a build on an older branch where it used to create a `mas` build. This is also now changed to `mas-arm64`. How do I change it back to `mas` builds?

Update:

If I change my `"electron-build": "electron-builder -m"` into `"electron-build": "electron-builder -m --x64"`, it will work again. But this was previously not needed, how can I make this parameter redundant?